# SharePoint2013 online - Yammer log in screen closes by itself in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint, yammer

Yammer log in screen doesn't work in IE. we are using yammer javascript SDK to include yammer log in button in our SharePoint page. If a user clicks on the button in IE, yammer login page opens and when user enters the user name in login form it gives a javascript popup to close the window(or sometimes the screen goes blank).

We have added yammer.com and our SharePoint site in trusted sites. Also added en-US language in browser.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Share your relevant code part.

Answer (score 0):

You made need to add a couple more addresses to your trusted sites.

[Add to trusted sites](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24905.sharepoint-2013-blank-dialog-box-pops-up-on-login-when-using-internet-explorer-for-yammer-app-on-premises.aspx)

Comment: Please include (at least) a summary of linked articles directly in your post. This is important for the site, in case the link breaks in the future and people are still looking for answers to the original question.